# Acquiring French Nationality through a parent

Tags: france

My father was a French citizen while Djibouti was still colonized by France. My father’s passport was expired on 1978 and it was not renewed and canceled. He then used the Djibouti passport to move to the Middle-east where my siblings and I were born. 
My question is, can I apply for the French citizenship through him? Sadly my father passed away, so I don’t know whether he had the right to claim it or not.

Comment: When was that passport issued?

Comment: Then you may be in luck.  There is a 50-year rule that I don't quite understand, but you are within the 50 years.  You will probably have to show that you acquired French citizenship at your birth (this will depend on French nationality law at the time of your birth, and assumes that your father did not lose his French nationality between 1973 and your birth), and that you have not lost it since you were born.

Comment: Sorry the passport was issued on 1975. However the French passport was not renewed and canceled in 1978 and then my father kept his Djibouti passport and hence my his nationality on my birth certificate is Djibouti and so is mine.

Comment: the French passport was cancelled? By "not renewed" do you mean that renewal was refused?  Why?

Comment: Was your father living in Djibouti at the time of independence?

Comment: My father was living abroad when Djibouti got its independence ( June1977) but he was still visiting Djibouti from time to time. The passport was not renewed probably due to the independence of Djibouti.

Comment: I asked because if your father was not residing in France at the time of independence and did not explicitly apply for retention of French nationality at the time of independence, then he automatically lost it upon independence and became a Djibouti national. Thus, you would have no right to French nationality as a result.